# Bypass a push id node in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting a null when I try to get data of the child node of a push id. My structure look like this
[image]
And this is my code for getting the message data

```
DatabaseReference mMessageDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("private_messages");
mMessageDatabase.child(User1).child(User2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {

                // getting null in message
                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
                Log.e(TAG, "CHAT_LOG: " + message);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Is there something wrong in my code or Am I missing a code there?

## EDIT:

I try using a query to test if it gives me data. heres my code

```
        messageDatabase.orderByChild("seen").equalTo("false")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String key = datas.getKey();
                                String seen = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("seen").getValue(String.class);
                                Log.e(TAG, "CHAT_LOG: Seen= " + seen);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Fortunately it gives me a data. THe only problem is getting the message. I used a query here and I need to give a specific value to it.

Comment: Cand please post your real database structure by adding a screenshot of it?

Comment: @AlexMamo I uploaded the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 mMessageDatabase.child(User1).child(User2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
           for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            String message = datas.child("message").getValue(String.class);
            Log.e(TAG, "CHAT_LOG: " + message);
           }
        }
    }
```

Since the snapshot is at `User2` then you can loop inside the direct child which is the push id and retrieve the value of child `message`

Comment: It does'nt give me any value. I tried to check it by `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();` it says 0

Comment: No changes from the Log

Comment: @xxxQDAxxx if it gives you the data according to the edit, then what is the problem?!

Comment: I use that code inside a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and on PopulateView. It always shows the last item of the child node

Comment: the adapter will show you the data where `seen=false`

Comment: is there a way to get the index too?

Comment: the key? You are getting it like this `String key = datas.getKey();` also use addValueEventListener instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: @xxxQDAxxx okay if the answer helped please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you!

Comment: just update your code. Change addListenerForSingleValueEvent to addValueEventListener. Thanks!